# Obtener valor de una celda DataGridView y pasarlo a String y formatearlo

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Tengo un DataGridView el cual recorro y obtengo el valor de cada celda y lo almaceno en una lista de strings
yo quiero al valor obtenido de la celda del DatGridView aplicarle un formato antes de ingresarlo en la lista

Este es mi codigo:

```
    private List<string> ListaConLosValoresDelDataGrid(){
      List<string> lista = new List<string>();
      for(int fila = 0; fila < dg.Rows[i].Cells.Count; fila++){
        for(int columna = 0; columna < columnas.Count; columna++){
          lista.Add(dgvNumeros.Rows[fila].Columns[columna].value.ToString());
        }
      }
    }
```

normalmente el formato se lo agregaría como parámetro del ToString pero dicho ToSting no cuenta con una sobrecarga que me permita pasarle parámetros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la idea es aplicar un formato numerico primero debes obtener ese tipo de dato casteando el valor, despues aplicas el formato

```
private List<string> ListaConLosValoresDelDataGrid()
{
  List<string> lista = new List<string>();

  for(int fila = 0; fila < dg.Rows[i].Cells.Count; fila++)
  {
    for(int columna = 0; columna < columnas.Count; columna++)
    {
      int valor = Convert.ToInt32(dgvNumeros.Rows[fila].Columns[columna].Value);
      lista.Add(valor.ToString("N2"));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. Pude resolverlo utilizando la propiedad FormattedValue

Comment: pero el FormattedValue  es una propiedad para darle formato a la celda del grid, no para tomar el valor y asignarlo en la lista